# How can I crop image into circle in DirectX

Tags: c++, c, directx, directx-11

I would like to know how to crop image in **directx** with circle. It doesn't matter how the crop would be(with a geometry or another image).

```
    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID2D1Effect> hueRotationEffect;
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID2D1Effect> shadowEffect;
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID2D1Effect> affineTransformEffect;
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID2D1Effect> compositeEffect;
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID2D1EllipseGeometry> unitEllipseGeometry;
ID2D1Factory* factory;

context2->CreateEffect(CLSID_D2D1Shadow, &shadowEffect);
context2->CreateEffect(CLSID_D2D12DAffineTransform, &affineTransformEffect);
context2->CreateEffect(CLSID_D2D1Composite, &compositeEffect);
context2->CreateEffect(CLSID_D2D1HueRotation, &hueRotationEffect);

//Effect of hue
hueRotationEffect->SetInput(1, tetronimoBitmap.Get());
hueRotationEffect->SetValue(D2D1_HUEROTATION_PROP_ANGLE, 270.0f);

//Effect of shader
shadowEffect->SetInput(0, tetronimoBitmap.Get());
affineTransformEffect->SetInputEffect(0, shadowEffect.Get());

D2D1_MATRIX_3X2_F matrix = D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Translation(20, 20);

affineTransformEffect->SetValue(D2D1_2DAFFINETRANSFORM_PROP_TRANSFORM_MATRIX, matrix);

compositeEffect->SetInput(1, tetronimoBitmap.Get());
compositeEffect->SetInputEffect(0, affineTransformEffect.Get());
hueRotationEffect->SetInputEffect(0, compositeEffect.Get());

//rectImage = { width,height, tetronimoBitmap->GetSize().width, tetronimoBitmap->GetSize().height };

context2->DrawImage(hueRotationEffect.Get(), D2D1::Point2F(100, 100));
```

Comment: I think I would provide a circular mask texture to the pixel shader and use it's alpha to mask the color texture.

Comment: I'm new to DirectX can you go more thorough

Comment: Another option: render the image to a quad with a fragment shader that sets the alpha component to 0 if `sqrt((texcoord.x - 0.5)**2 + (texcoord.y - 0.5)**2) > crop_radius`

Comment: @Botje I like that.

Comment: @Stepan TBH I am no expert, but have done a bit of DirectX11 (2D game engine).  Both mine and Botje's suggestion require shader programming (mine is a pixel shader solution and Bothe's is a fragment shader solution) so you need to start learning about writing custom shaders, which is the most fun bit about modern graphics programming anyway, so you will enjoy it.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. In the above i posted the code.